# How to assign a dynamically updating date to a user based on a related field on their profile

Tags: views, datetime, entities

I have a site where Users who can expect a delivery to their address every week depending on their delivery route. I also have a Content Type of "Delivery Route" and a Content Type of "Delivery" with a Date field and an entity reference field that adds related delivery routes for each delivery. With this I have a couple issues:

1: How to automatically assign a user a delivery route based on the ZIP code of their delivery address entered upon registration (Using the [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module).

2: How to display the next upcoming delivery date for a particular user on their profile based on deliveries collected for their delivery route.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty broad question... Can you elaborate more? For instance, how would you do this manually?

Comment: I've been struggling with how to set this up, sorry for the broad question. Using Entity Reference fields, Views, and the Date module, how do I assign each user a Delivery Route and each Delivery Route a list of delivery dates, then let the user know what their next delivery date is based on their delivery route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I discovered that it can be handled using Views with Entity Reference.

For the first part, assigning a delivery route based on the zip code, I used [Entity Reference Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) and created a link from a custom landing page that populated the user's route. Although I think rooby's answer might still be a good path.

For the second part I used a Views block on the user's account page to display a message about the next upcoming delivery date for the route assigned to that user. Here's what I did:

1. Create a Content Type of "Delivery" with a Delivery Date [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field and a Entity Reference field to reference the Delivery Route entity.
2. Create a block view of Delivery nodes:

   • Add the Delivery Date field

   • Add a relationship to entity referenced from field_delivery_routes

   • Add a relationship to the User referencing field_user_delivery_route using the relationship from above (field_delivery_routes). Check "Require this relationship."

   • Add a contextual filter for User: Uid (User referencing Content from field_user_delivery_route). Choose When the filter value is NOT available, Provide default value: User ID from URL.

   •  Now the view can be sorted by Content:Delivery Date (asc), specifying only 1 item displayed in the view or by using Filter Criteria with Date Views (submodule of Date) to only show dates within a certain range.
3. Display the Views Block on the User profile page.

I'm also hopeful that this view can be used with [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva) or [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to create an actual field to display on the user's account.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do those things without coding.

You can use the [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to add a field to the user's profile that references the relevant delivery route node.

Then you can use the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, along with the [rules conditional](http://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to do the rest.

Have a rule that on user registration, uses the "Fetch entity by property" action to load the node that has the matching post code.

Then use the "Set a data value" action to set the value of the entity reference field for that user, based on the fetched entity.

Have another rule for when a user profile is viewed that uses the "Fetch entity by ID" action to load the delivery route node for that user.

Then add an if conditional that checks the entity type and content type, or use "Entity has field" and check that the date field is present. This step is required for you to be able to use all the fields on the fetched node in later actions.

Then you can use the "Show a message on the site" action to show a message to the user, in which you can use tokens to show the value of the date field attached to that delivery route node.

Comment: Sounds promising.. :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer here and it does seem promising but I was able to handle it using Entity Reference, Entity Reference Prepopulate, Views and Date Views. It is inspiring that more than I thought can be handled with Rules and Rules Conditional, so I'm looking forward to investigating that more.

Comment: Yeah, I've been digging into rules a bit lately and you can do pretty much anything you want. Every now and then you might have to make a custom action or something but it can do a hell of a lot.